# android expandablelistview using phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, expandablelistview

I am new to phonegap. I am finding `expandablelistview` in Android using phonegap, and also need the tabbar using the same.  How can it be possible? I am looking for some example or some tutorial about this. Is it possible using the `PHONEGAP`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Collapsible content for replacing
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/content-collapsible.html